# Laravel 5.5 Assign jobs to student

Tags: laravel

```
$students = Enrollment::all();

    foreach ($students as $student) {

        $assign_course_id = $student->course_id;
        $assign_user_id = $student->user_id;
        //echo $assign_user_id;

        $assign_jobs = Submission::all();
        $collection = collect($assign_jobs);
        $merged = $collection->merge($assign_jobs)->random(2);
        //echo $merged;

        if (count($merged) > 0) {

            for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($merged); $i++) {
                $jobid = $merged[$i]->id;

                foreach ($merged as $job) {

                    if ($assign_user_id !== $job->user_id) {

                        $newjob = New PeerMarking;
                        $newjob->submission_id = $jobid;
                        $newjob->course_id = $assign_course_id;
                        $newjob->user_id = $assign_user_id;
                        $newjob->save();
                        //echo $assign_user_id;
                    }

                    // $merged = $collection->merge($assign_jobs)->random(2);
                    //
                    // $newjob = New AssignJob;
                    // $newjob->submission_id = $jobid;
                    // $newjob->course_id = $assign_course_id;
                    // $newjob->user_id = $assign_user_id;
                    // $newjob->save();
                }

            }

        }

    }
```

I want to assign jobs to current enrolled students.
One student gains two submissions and one submission will be marked twice.
Student only can gain others job, can not gain self's job. 
For now, my database is looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Can you be more clear on what you specifically want to know? SO is for helping out with specific issues, not with writing the code for you.

Comment: This is a peer marking system. I want to assign jobs to students to mark. One student can get two jobs. One job will be mark twice. There is a condition that student can not get their own job.